# ubuntu: Apache won't start

Tags: ubuntu

I just installed apache on ubuntu 10.04. When I try to start apache, It tries to bind to 0.0.0.0:80 then fails. What am I doing wrong here?

```
sparky$ sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart

(98)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
Unable to open logs
```

Looking at what else is on port 80:

```
sparky$  sudo netstat -lnp | grep '80'

tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1483/netxserv   
udp6       0      0 fe80::280:64ff:fe9c:123 :::*                                1244/ntpd       
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     4809     1177/pulseaudio     /home/admin/.pulse/843e513a62d1b128539d25a14dce36b8-runtime/native
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     4056     985/launcher        /tmp/orbit-admin/linc-3d9-0-680082d3cdbb
```

My Hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost.localdomain   localhost

10.10.7.139 sparky.abcco.local sparky
```

Comment: netxserv is using that port, as you can see in your netstat output.

Comment: netxserv is on 80 so apache wont start. I think netxserv is some kind of sip/IPphone software, you will need to stop this before you can run apache. could try killall -9 netxserv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line

```
tcp      0    0 0.0.0.0:80            0.0.0.0:*          LISTEN     1483/netxserv
```

shows that netsxerv is running and bound to port 80. Presumably you have a reason to run netxserv on port 80 so you will need to reconfigure it to listen on a different port or run apache on a different port.